# Flask how to pass list of list to javascript

Tags: python, flask, jinja2

I want to pass query results as a list to javascript

**Python**

```
dataSet = []
result = db.engine.execute("SELECT * FROM ....")
for g in result :
    dataSet.append(g)
return render_template('webpage.html', title=_('title'), dataSet=dataSet)
```

**HTML**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var dataSets = {{ dataSet | safe }};
</script>
```

this injects list like `[(item1), (item2)]` but i need it to be like `[[item1], [item2]]` to pass javascript and continue there

can't figure it out. Tried numpy arrays but it won't insert "," comma between elements.

Comment: Did you double check the datatype of each `g` you are appending to the `dataSet` list inside your Python code? Is each `g` a list or a tuple?

Comment: `dataSet.append(list(g))`